# How to return div with custom attributes(Coding a Gutenberg Block)

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I'm making a review widget that comes as a shortcode and Gutenberg block. The shortcode part was easy as I have built many shortcodes before, but I'm stuck on building my first Gutenberg block.

More specifically, I've learned how to build a block that outputs div with custom class, but I can't find how to add a custom div attribute anywhere...

Here's the code responsible for block output:

```
return el( 'div',
      {
         className: 'review-widget',
      }

   ); // End return
```

and this outputs

`<div class="review-widget"></div>`

properly.

However, I need to output a div like this:

`<div class="review-widget" data-limit="10"></div>`

but I'm having a hard time adding the data-limit="10" to the div.

I've tried:

```
return el( 'div',
      {
         className: 'review-widget',
         data-limit: 10
      }

   ); // End return
```

but it doesn't work...

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try returning JSX, skipping the `el` part:

```
return (
    <div
        className='review-widget'
        data-limit='10'
    >
    </div>
);
```

It may also be that you need to quote the 10 in your original `el` example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've tried both of them, but in both cases the custom block disappears from the editor- like the syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410377/how-to-add-data-attribute-without-value-in-react-create-element \o/

Both the attribute name and the attribute value should be wrapped in quotes:

```
return el( 'div',
      {
         className: 'review-widget',
         'data-limit': '10'
      }

   ); // End return
```